# Постоянный просмотр изменения данных в бд телеграм ботом

Tags: python, telebot, vkontakte-api, sqlite3

Есть два бота тг и вк. Бот в вк берет сообщения с объявлением о какой либо информации и добавляет их записью в таблицу в бд. Бот телеграмм должен постоянно посматривать добавление новых записей в таблицу вк ботом и дальше использовать их для каких либо задач. Но вот вопрос, как сделать в телеграмм боте постоянную проверку на наличие новых записей?

Comment: добавить инкрементное поле в бд, запрашивать каждый раз только записи у которых оно(новое поле) больше чем последнее известное боту =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков не очень понимаю

Comment: Проверять либо по таймеру, либо т-бот должен иметь хендл, обращение к которому инициирует проверку записей самим ботом. Генерировать события можно напрямую от вк-бота или от базы (триггер в Postgree c http.fetch).